# Installing Mini filter driver form WIX

Tags: .net, winapi, wix, windows-installer

I am Working on WIX installer. In that i have custom action to install the mini filter driver. In the custom action i have written the code to install mini filter driver using. inf file.

`"RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 128 .\Driver.inf"`

in command prompt, but it did not install it.

1. Can any one tell me is there any problem in the above command?
2. Or do i need to follow different steps to install.?

**Update:**

When i run the same command using "CMD" in admin mode then it installs the driver.

When i run the same command in a .NET process then it fails.

```cs
 string FileName = "rundll32.exe";
 string Arguments = @"SETUPAPI.DLL, InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 131 E:\del\FsFilter1.inf";
 ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FileName, Arguments);
 StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
 Process process = Process.Start(StartInfo);
 process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Consider using the custom action that WiX Toolset provides for this purpose. See [Driver Element (Difxapp Extension)](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/difxapp/driver.html) and this [tutorial](http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2008/10/21/installing-filter-drivers-with-difxapp-and-a-wix-v3-msi/).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Difxapp](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/difxapp/driver.html) extension. For a complete example look at this: [Installing filter drivers with DIFxApp and a WiX v3 MSI](http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2008/10/21/installing-filter-drivers-with-difxapp-and-a-wix-v3-msi/)